# Serializing AbstractTableModel fails when setting Look and Feel

Tags: java, exception, serialization, look-and-feel

Serializing a class that extends `AbstractTableModel` after having set a certain Look-and-Feel causes a `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle$Skin` exception, followed by different `NullPointerException`s.

I found a solution and are answering my own question to help others save hours, and implement serialization correctly from the beginning. Attached is a minimal example that reproduces the error on my machine (Win 10, Netbeans IDE 8.2, Java JDK 1.8). In the answer below are the main code segments together with more details.

Answer (score 2):

The main class extends `JFrame`, set the Look-and-Feel and shows a `JTable`. It has a member variable `Tip tip`, where `Tip` extends `AbstractTableModel` (see below).

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // a single tip
    // in my final app, there was a list of tips
    Tip tip = new Tip();

    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();

        // fill new instance with some dummy data for answers
        tip.addAnswer("first answer", 1, "first reply");
        tip.addAnswer("second answer", 2, "second reply");

        // assign the table model
        jTable.setModel(tip);
    }

    // ... more code (see attachment)

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Set the look and feel */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    /**
                     * when setting LaF to 'Nimbus' de-/serialization fails on the first save/load:
                     * Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
                     * at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:371)
                     * 
                     * when setting LaF to 'Windows' the second save/load fails with:
                     * java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle$Skin
                     * at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
                     * 
                     * when setting LaF to 'Metal' save/load works just fine
                     * 
                     * not setting LaF at all (uncomment the line below) also works fine
                     */
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

The class `Tip` holds some member variables that should be shown in the table (custom type `TipAnswer`), and also additional member variables that are required for business logic but don't show up in the table:

```
public class Tip extends AbstractTableModel {

    // ... more member variables that don't show up in the table

    // a list of answers to the tip which show up in the table
    private ArrayList<TipAnswer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    // adds an answer to the tip
    public void addAnswer(String answer, int cost, String reply) {    
        answers.add(new TipAnswer(answer, cost, reply));
    }

    // ... more methods that override the methods 
    //     required by AbstractTableModel (see attachment)
}
```

The main class reacts on the press of a button, upon which the member variable `tip` is serialized and right away deserialized again. The result of the deserialization is shown in the table.

```
private void jSaveAndLoadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // make temp file
    Path path;
    try {
        path = Files.createTempFile("TestTableModel", ".txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return;
    }

    // write to file (serialize)
    try ( FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                       StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                                                       StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
          ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(channel))
        ) {

        // write object to file
        oos.writeObject(tip);
        System.out.println("Tip table saved as " + path);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return;
    }

    // set an empty table model for demonstration purposes
    jTable.setModel(new Tip());

    // read from file (deserialize)
    Tip tipFromFile;
    try ( FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
          ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream (channel)) ) {

        // the instance to return
        tipFromFile = (Tip)ois.readObject();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return;
    }

    // store the tip which has just been read in this instance
    tip = tipFromFile;

    // show the tip in the table
    jTable.setModel(tip);
}
```

As indicated in the comments of the main class, saving and loading the `tip` works fine when no Look-and-Feel is set, or when 'Metal' is selected. Setting 'Nimbus' LaF, serialization fails with a `NullPointerException`. Setting 'Windows' LaF, serialization fails with a `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle$Skin` exception, at least on my machine.

Javadoc of `javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo` claims that it implements `Serializable`, so I wouldn't have expected this exception.

Inspecting the saved file with a text editor reveals that besides the member varialbes of  `tip` many other fields are stored as well, such as `javax.swing.event.TableModelListeners`, `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` and many more. At first I suspected that this causes the exception and I just need to override the `writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)` and `writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)` in class `Tip`, but the additional fields are still saved to disk. On a second thought it's clear why. Interestingly, I wouldn't have guessed that additional fields are saved as I cannot find a hint to those fields in the javadoc of `AbstractTableModel` nor in `TableModel`, but well, not so critical.

So what helped was to implement a separate class `TipTableModel extends AbstractTableMode` that receives the `tip` upon instantiation:

```
public TipTableModel(Tip tip) {
    this.tip = tip;
}
```

So instead of serializing the variable of a type that implements `AbstractTableModel`, it seems advisable to separate the data from the table model and serialize the data only.

Upon debugging, I also realized that objects that extend `AbstractListModel` (List, not Table) also save many fields in addition to the member variables that are declared in the class, but serializing these members did not cause any exceptions, although it would probably be advisable too to separate data and the list model.

Resume: 1) Always implement the data and the table model in two separate classes. 2) Maybe certain Look-and-Feels need to be enhanced (although I still believe that I made a mistake not the developers of Java), and 3) add a comment to javadoc of `AbstractTableModel` to clarify that many non-obvious fields are serialized as well.

[Netbeans project of this example](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/yoF8EYvhY5Lb6Yn).